# Oracle: Conversion from WE8ISO8859P1 to AL32UTF8

Tags: import, export, data-conversion, oracle11gr2, character-set

I am trying to consolidate some databases and I have some problems with CHARACTER Sets.

My database looks like this:

**Source Database**

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8ISO8859P1
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
```

**Destination Database**

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
```

I made an export to a schema, but when I imported in the new database I have a lot of errors like:

```
ORA-02374: conversion error loading table owner.table_name
ORA-12899: value too large for column col_name (actual: 403, maximum: 400)
```

I have run the **csscan** utility. Here is the result:

```
TABLE   Convertible    Truncation        Lossy
------ ------------- ------------- ------------
    1            0             18           24
    2        2,248            120       19,854
    3        2,155            120       19,551
    4        5,431            294       41,531
    5        5,925            114       18,352
    6          129              4        5,095
    7          109              4        5,017
    8        2,149            151        5,219
------ ------------- ------------- -------------
```

So, there is any way to find out the value of VARCHAR2 in destination before the import? I can alter the structure of the tables. In our example I can alter my table and modify the size of column from 400 to 403.

If you need more information or anything else, please leave a comment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still no solution for my problem. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csscan tool will tell you how big the Truction records will be after the conversion, and you can use that to change the size of your field. In following example, you need to change your the size of SAMPLE_COLUMN from VARCHAR(40) to VARCHAR(43) to cover everything that is being converted:

csscan .err sample output:

```
User  : SAMPLE_USER
Table : SAMPLE_TABLE
Column: SAMPLE_COLUMN
Type  : VARCHAR2(40)
Number of Exceptions         : 5
Max Post Conversion Data Size: 43
```

Hope this helps.